# How to find all common elements in n sorted string arrays?

Tags: java, arrays

I have multiple variable-size string arrays that are pre-sorted and I need to find all elements contained in each array. For example, if I have arrays

```
 {"cat", "dog", "horse"}, 
 {"dog", "donkey", "horse"},
 {"cat", "dog", "donkey", "horse"}
```

I want the result array to be

```
{"dog", "horse"}
```

What would be an effective way to accomplish this?

Comment: do you have 3 arrays or more constant or even dynamic count of arrays? (not elements, but different arrays)

Comment: Sounds like homework...

Comment: The number of arrays is variable. In some cases it could be just one or it could be upwards of 100. I am filling the arrays from the result of a user query into an hbase table which is naturally pre-sorted.

Comment: An alternate way, you can convert your arrays into Sets then use Google Guvava's Sets.intersection() method to get common elements.

Comment: Start with the first array and edit it as needed based on the what you find comparing it to the other arrays

Comment: Lookup `Collection.retainAll()` which should do the trick for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given three arrays

```
String[] arr1 = {"cat", "dog", "horse"};
String[] arr1 = {"dog", "donkey", "horse"};
String[] arr1 =  {"cat", "dog", "donkey", "horse"};
```

Create three *Set*s from them either by iterating the elements one by one or by following

```
Set<String> set1 = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(arr1));
Set<String> set2 = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(arr2));
Set<String> set3 = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(arr3));
```

Now perform set intersection by calling *retainAll* function given in set interface

```
/* set1 intersection set2: results in set1 having only common elements */
set1.retainAll(set2);
/* Finally intersection of previous result and set3: final result in set1 */
set1.retainAll(set3);
```

For more information on *Set* operations supported in java collection refer [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html)

Answer (score 1):

I'll describe an algorithm assuming that the arrays are sorted in *ascending* order

Make an index for each of the 3 arrays, and set it to 0.

Determine which element at the array's index is the smallest, and increment the index for that array.

if the smallest element is at the beginning of two arrays, you've found a duplicate.

you can increment both(all) of their indices.

This algorithm should take **O(n)** time.

---

It may or may not be possible for arrays to have two of the same element.  If it is possible, you might have to keep track of an array's previous element and compare it to the current element to find those kind of duplicates.

Comment: Thank you. This is much better than what I had in mind

Answer (score 1):

How about this...

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class CommonElements {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] one = {"cat", "dog", "horse"};
        String[] two = {"dog", "donkey", "horse"};
        String[] three = {"cat", "dog", "donkey", "horse"};

        List<String> result = findCommonElements(one, two, three);

        for (String s : result)
            System.out.println(s);
    }

    public static List<String> findCommonElements(String[] ... args) {
        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        for (String[] strings : args) {
            for (String s : strings) {
                Integer current = map.get(s);
                map.put(s, current == null ? 1 : current + 1);
            }
        }

        List<String> result = new LinkedList<String>();
        for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet())
            if (entry.getValue() == args.length)
                result.add(entry.getKey());

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I like that because Maps allow duplicates, where Sets do not.

Answer (score 0):

```
set pointers to start
while no array exhausted
  max_value = max value over pointers
  for each array
    while value at pointer < max_value
      increment pointer
      if array exhausted
        exit program
  for each array
    if value at pointer != max_value
      continue // restart from line 3
  print max_value
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll definitely want to keep your multiple arrays in an array of its own, ie: a multi-dimensional array. What you COULD do then is have a second array and loop through your multi array..... put every possible element into this new array... ie: {cat, dog, horse, donkey}

Once this is done you can cycle through your arrays and compare them to the "master array" with all elements. If an array does not contain an element thats in the master array, remove that element from master. At the end, the master array will contain all elements that are in every one of your original arrays. I admit there may be a more elegant solution... but this will work!

Answer (score 0):

I would first get the length of the biggest array and initialize a new result array to that length. Then using nested loops compare the elements in each of the already created string arrays, e.g. compare elements 'cat', 'dog', cat. As they're not equal, move up one position in the innermost array, compare 'cat', 'dog', 'dog', etc. If the value of the element is equal in all arrays, add that element to the result array.

From there you should be able to write a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

I like solution about set intersection, but also want to suggest my:

```
final String array[][] = {
     {"cat", "dog", "horse"}, 
     {"dog", "donkey", "horse"},
     {"cat", "dog", "donkey", "horse"},
     // add more arrays here
     };

final HashMap <String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>(array.length);
for (final String[] iArray : array)
    for (final String element: iArray)
    {
        if (map.containsKey(element))
            map.put(element, map.get(element) + 1);
        else
            map.put(element, 1);
    }

for (final String element: map.keySet())
    if (map.get(element) == array.length)
        System.out.println("keyword " + element + " exists in all arrays");
```

Answer (score -1):

`Arrays.asList(...).contains(...)`. This allows you to convert your array to a list, and simply see if the array contains the element without having to iterate through it. If it does, continue checking the other arrays to see if it is a common element across all of them.

Comment: Downvote? Care to explain?

Comment: I downvoted.  I'm downvoting every answer that suggests library functionality that doesn't take advantage of the fact that the arrays are homework

Comment: @SamIam Why would you do such a thing?  Learning how to refer to the libraries and use them as needed is a huge part of becoming a good programmer.  I think we should consider your downvotes to be upvotes.

Answer (score -2):

You could put yours arrays to `java.util.Set`, and just to call method `contains` on each Set. (f.e `set.contains("horse")`); if it contains same string it will return `true`, otherwise `false`, then check all results.